# date command output linux

Tags: linux, date

On one system I'm getting date command output like below

```
system1# date 
Thu Oct 18 10:34:36 BST 2018
```

while another  similar box  is showing it like

```
system2#date 
Thu 18 Oct 10:34:50 BST 2018
```

Both showing Month at different column. When I do an

```
env LC_ALL=C date
```

on the system2 , I get it in normal way as "Thu Oct 18 10:34:36 BST 2018"

on both system, the local shows same without any difference.

```
#locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

any idea

Comment: What is `env LC_ALL date` meant to do? This command fails for me, with `env: ‘LC_ALL’: No such file or directory`. The system2 `date` is the correct format for your locale. What is the output of `LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8" date` on both systems?

Comment: apologies, its  env LC_ALL=C date which gives me the standard date on system2

Comment: just run `tzselect` on your machine and off you go.

Comment: Nasir, your question got cut off. “Any idea ... why system1 is showing the date differently from system2 and how can I make system2’s date look like system1’s?” Maybe?

Comment: What are the two OS versions? What are the locale definitions? Please post the output of locale date_fmt from either.

Comment: Okay, but what about the other question in my comment?

Comment: system1 is debian wheezy 7.11 while system2  is debian jessie 8.10 .

Answer (score 2):

So you get the output in the US format (when LC_ALL is set to the default) or you get it in the English variant.

Note that the strange order in the date format used by the US people is used in very few other countries as well...and definitely not in England

So if you like the same output on both system, set up the same locale on both systems or use the explicit date format:

```
date '+%a %b %e %T %Z %Y'
```

This example uses the date format that is the default for the C locale.

Comment: my concern is that even the local output on both systems is exactly same as I have already posted in my OP, the system2 is showing month in different column than standard. what is causing this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a standard date output, use the ISO 8601 flag

```
robert@pip2:/tmp$ date
Thu May 30 07:16:51 PDT 2019
robert@pip2:/tmp$ date --iso-8601
2019-05-30
robert@pip2:/tmp$
```